# ¿Cómo crear perfil de Usuario al Registrarme o Iniciar Sesión en Django?

Tags: python, django, lms

Estoy haciendo un sistema de cursos, y al momento de crear una nueva cuenta se crea perfectamente, pero no se crea el perfil de usuario al crear la cuenta, cómo podría lograr esto? Aquí comparto mi signals.py, y algunas clases:

signals.py

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    
    
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

En las vistas tengo lo siguiente por ejemplo:

```py
@login_required()
def profile(request):
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

Esta línea es la clave para crear el perfil:

```py
Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

Pero solo lo crea cuando ingreso a la vista del perfil, pero cuando uno se registra, le pide al usuario que inicie sesión, y en ese momento lo redirige a la home (página principal) y ahí ya debería ya estar creado.

Hay algún paso que estoy olvidando? Porque me parece que se debería crear el perfil al momento de que se cree o se loguee el usuario.

Comment: Te recomiendo que elimines esa vista, cada vez que el usuario entra a su perfil se estaría llamando esa función, es una muy mala práctica

Comment: Si, estuve revisando otras páginas y decían eso mismo que era una mala práctica utilizar esta función Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user), no lo sabía

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile/**Models.py**

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    Signals the Profile about User creation.
    """
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Lo que hace esta función es revisar si se registró un nuevo usuario en el modelo **User**. Luego del registro se crea un perfil automáticamente.

Crear el perfil con el modelo, es más seguro y fácil.

Comment: Sos muy crack! Pero por qué no me funciona esto en el signals.py, que estoy haciendo mal? Porque debería funcionar igualmente... Lo puse en el models.py y funciona de maravilla